# How to use the coords from locationManager in local HTML file?

Tags: html, xcode, cllocationmanager

Since iOS 6 has a bug with GeoLocation/WatchPosition to obtain the users position, I am implenting in xcode the locationManager and get the coordinates.

But, I want to use these coords in a local HTML (webView) file.
Is it possible to use,send or call the coords from locationManager to the HTML / JavaScript file?

EDIT:

I thought about a possible solution... cookies... can that be done because I can not get a output in my code below:

EDIT 2:
Yes it can... I adjust the code below and it works. Important is the Cookie domain and path option so webView (HTML) can get the cookie.

But if someone knows a better solution, please let me know, i like to learn!

```
- (void)applicationdidBecomeActive {     
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways]; 
} 

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    ...      

    NSLog(@"%@", DevicePosition);
    NSDictionary *newCookieDict = [NSMutableDictionary
                                   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @".^filecookies^", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                   @"DevicePos", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                   @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                   DevicePosition, NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                   //@"2012-01-01 12:00:00 -0100", NSHTTPCookieExpires,
                                   nil];
    //create a new cookie
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie
                            cookieWithProperties:newCookieDict];
    //add the new cookie
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];

    // dev cookie controle
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", cookie);
}
```

HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function getCookie(name)    {        
        var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");        
        var value = re.exec(document.cookie);        
        return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;   
        } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to soluve your question.
You can use WebViewJavascriptBridge to 'populate' a Objective C's method to webview, so your html page can access that method via window.xxx to invoke the method implemented in Objective C.

Please take a look at https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge